# How do I tell real CPU load in a xen environment?

Tags: virtualization, xen, top

I have a Debian machine with 4 CPU cores [running Xen](http://wiki.debian.org/Xen) with two virtual machines, and I'm having trouble determining overall real CPU usage.

Each machine has two VCPUs assigned to it with no cap on CPU use:

```
Domain-0                             0    256    0
dom01                                1    256    0
dom02                                4    256    0
```

While logged into each of those machines, `top` shows 80-90% CPU usage on each CPU (I press '1' to show each core individually).  `xentop` on dom0 agrees with this report.

However, `top` on dom0 shows all 4 CPU cores spending most of their time idle.

Does xen hide the CPU utilization of the virtual environments from dom0's `top`?  If so, is there any way to display the real utilization of the CPU cores on the machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct, dom0 doesn't see domU CPU activity.

The answer is in your question: `xentop` on dom0 shows you the real utilization of the CPUs.

Comment: I don't see any way to view the utilization of individual CPU cores in xentop, only the total CPU % used by each virtual machine.  Is there any way to get a per-core total?

Comment: To get a per-core total of CPU usage hit `V` in `xentop`.

Comment: That gives per-VCPU total seconds.  But no CPU %, which is what I'm after.

Comment: … yeah, you asked for a 'per-core total'.

Comment: If it's important to you to see CPU%, you can try adding that functionality to `xentop` :) Or source dive to figure out where it's getting the information from.

Comment: Yes, percent of CPU per core total.  Like CPU core 1: 95%, 2: 90% 3: 86% and so on.